# Case feed is not displaying as rich html format in classic?

Tags: salesforce-classic, casefeed

Case feeds in lightning view is not displaying properly styles,links,images,etc.. are missing from the case feed. how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Looks like image is not attached. Attache it and share what you have done to resolve it.

Comment: it is not an image. It's a link

Comment: it should take <a> tag but it's displaying link as text

Comment: this is email feed. link in the email is not formatted properly in lightning view it is working fine and in classic it's looks line this

Comment: *like this [link](http://example.com)